# Shouldnt the magnetic field at a certain angle be minimum in center of current loop?

Tags: current, coil, magnetics, wire-loop

Magnetic field is strongest at the center of current loop. But if it is calculated along a single magnetic field line like this: A and B are magnetic lines.
[image]

Shouldnt it minimum in the center since there would an equal force pulling it in opposite direction? Shouldnt it form an equilibirum?

Answer (score 2):

A and B are incorrect.

[image]

*Figure 1. The magnetic field is as shown in this diagram and not radial as shown in OP's diagram. Source [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html).*

The nett effect is that all portions of the loop add to the overall magnetic field strength.

Answer (score 1):

This is Amperes Law at work here, so the Magnetic field that surrounds the wire is proportional to current going through the wire.

It always follows the "Right Hand rule" with respect to conventional current, and the magnetic field strength around the wire drops off in intensity at \$1/r\$ with \$r\$ being the radius distance from the wire.

The magnetic field circles the wire, its not like a net.

See [here](http://www.maxwells-equations.com/ampere/amperes-law.php)

So assuming that the loop is evenly symmetrical with the current constant then all the magnetic field lines will add up within the space plane of the loop and give an almost even spread of field intensity.

Answer (score 1):

> Magnetic field is strongest at the center of current loop.

Incorrect. The magnetic flux density is always strongest closest to the current carrying conductor. The Biot Savart law: -

[image]

Any small section of current has an effect on any point in space and, as can be seen the flux density at distance r reduces as \$r^2\$.

Given that the fields from opposing sides of the coil are in phase the flux density is additive inside the coil but still a minimum at the centre: -

[image]

Comment: Actually is it really at a minimum? I realise that what I said is not true, but if the loop is symmetrical and the current is constant and in phase then wouldn't all the field lines even out over the space within the loop? Meaning the intensity at any point within the cross-section plane that the loop resides would be the same?

Comment: @crowie if you had a high permeability material or a multi turn long solenoid I would agree but, for a single turn, no, intensity would be minimum at the centre.

Comment: yea I agree too basically because of the \$r^2\$ being non linear